# How to set screen size by phantomjs in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, screen-size

How to set screen size by phantomJS in selenium using python?
The size can be read by JS.

code here:

```
driver = PhantomJS()

print driver.get_window_size() # output: {u'width': 400, u'height': 300}

driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
print driver.get_window_size() # output: {u'width': 1920, u'height': 1280}

# get screen width and height by js, always 1024 * 768
print driver.execute_script('return window.screen.width') # output: 1024
print driver.execute_script('return window.screen.height') # output: 768
```

Get screen size by js, always 1024 * 768.

Comment: i don't think there's anything wrong with your code. i just don't think the executed script is returning the proper numbers. if you run `driver.save_screenshot('test.png')`, you will see the broswer window is set to the size specified in `driver.set_window_size()`. you'll easily see this if you set the window size to something more portrait like `driver.set_window_size(1440, 3440)`